# Rails 3 Routing Error uninitialized constant ApplicationController on Hello World

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I there. So i am new to Rails 3, trying to execute a simple hello world com a sql lite db, but i keep getting a

> uninitialized constant ApplicationController

my routes are :

```
LoadTest::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/hello' => 'hello#hello' , :as => :hello
  match "/erb_sql" => "hello#hellodb", :as => :erb_sql

end
```

my controller :

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
    def hello
        render :text => "Hello World!"
    end
    def hellodb
        @data = Hello.all
    end
end
```

and my view (hellodb.html.erb):

```
<table border="1">
        <% for row in @data %>
            <tr><td><%=h row.id %></td><td><%=h row.data %></td></tr>
        <% end %>
</table>
```

and my model :

```
class Hello < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you have application_controller.rb?

Comment: no.. what should i put in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have `application_controller.rb`. That's the basic controller, other controllers inherit from it.

I don't know how you've created your application, because the correct way to do it is running `rails new application_name` in a console. The whole structure including `application_controller.rb` will then be created in application_name folder.

Comment: i accidentely deleted that file i guess. its now working. thanks